# Magento - Programatically retrieve and set admin users status

Tags: php, magento

For a custom extension I'm building I need to be able to set and retrieve the status of an administrator user (not a customer) in Magento. I imagine you could achieve this like so;

```
$id; // ID of user stored here
$user = $mage->getadminuser($id); // store the user as an object or array in a variable with ID
$user->getStatus(); // return either true or false?
$user->setStatus(active or not active); // activate or deactivate the user
```

If anyone could provide me with the code to do this or documentation where I can find this easily?
Thanks!

Comment: Try Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('admin')->setStatus($password)->save();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = 5;
$admin = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($id);
if ($admin->getId()){
    $admin->setIsActive(1);//or 0
    $admin->save();
}
```